# How can I allow user to download offline maps from another android app?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-permissions

We are working on an android app, where we want to provide a feature to the users to download offline google maps from our app itself so that user doesn't have to go to google maps just for downloading the offline maps. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Using Google map data, or some other map provider?